# Stock management of assemblies and its sub parts (relationships)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-relations

I have to track the stock of individual parts and kits (assemblies) and can't find a satisfactory way of doing this.
Sample bogus and hyper simplified database:

```
Table prod:
prodID  1
prodName Flux capacitor
prodCost 900
prodPrice 1350 (900*1.5)
prodStock 3
-
prodID  2
prodName Mr Fusion
prodCost 300
prodPrice 600 (300*2)
prodStock 2
-
prodID  3
prodName Time travel kit
prodCost 1200 (900+300)
prodPrice 1560 (1200*1.3)
prodStock 2

Table rels
relID  1
relSrc  1 (Flux capacitor)
relType  4 (is a subpart of)
relDst  3 (Time travel kit)
-
relID  2
relSrc  2 (Mr Fusion)
relType  4 (is a subpart of)
relDst  3 (Time travel kit)
```

prodPrice: it's calculated based on the cost but not in a linear way. In this example for costs of 500 or less, the markup is a 200%. For costs of 500-1000 the markup is 150%. For costs of 1000+ the markup is 130%
That's why the time travel kit is much cheaper than the individual parts

prodStock: here is my problem. I can sell kits or the individual parts, So the stock of the kits is virtual.

The problem when I buy:
Some providers sell me the Time Travel kit as a whole (with one barcode) and some sells me the individual parts (with a different barcode)
So when I load the stock I don't know how to impute it.

The problem when I sell:
If I only sell kits, calculate the stock would be easy: "I have 3 Flux capacitors and 2 Mr Fusions, so I have 2 Time travel kits and a Flux Capacitor"
But I can sell Kits or individual parts. So, I have to track the stock of the individual parts and the possible kits at the same time (and I have to compensate for the sell price)

Probably this is really simple, but I can't see a simple solution.
Resuming: I have to find a way of tracking the stock and the database/program is the one who has to do it (I cant ask the clerk to correct the stock)

I'm using php+MySql. But this is more a logical problem than a programing one

Update: Sadly Eagle's solution wont work.

- the relationships can and are recursive (one kit uses another kit)
- There are kit that does use more than one of the same part (2 flux capacitors + 1 Mr Fusion)
- I really need to store a value for the stock of the kit. The same database is used for the web page where users want to buy the parts. And I should show the avaliable stock (otherwise they wont even try to buy). And can't afford to calculate the stock on every user search on the web page

**But I liked the idea of a boolean marking the stock as virtual**

Comment: Shouldn't `prodCost` of `prodID 3` be `900 + 300` (or at least `1350 + 600`)?

Comment: Yes, I changed my mind about the costs of the subparts and forgot to change the cost of the kit. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well first of all since the `prodStock` for the Time travel kit is virtual, you cannot store it in the database, it will essentially be a calculated field. It would probably help if you had a boolean on the table which says if the `prodStock` is calculated or not. I'll pretend as though you had this field in the table and I'll call it `isKit` for now (where `TRUE` implies it's a kit and the `prodStock` should be calculated).

Now to calculate the amount of each item that is in stock:

```
select p.prodID, p.prodName, p.prodCost, p.prodPrice, p.prodStock from prod p where not isKit
union all
select p.prodID, p.prodName, p.prodCost, p.prodPrice, min(c.prodStock) as prodStock
from 
  prod p
  inner join rels r on (p.prodID = r.relDst and r.relType = 4)
  inner join prod c on (r.relSrc = c.prodID and not c.isKit)
where p.isKit
group by p.prodID, p.prodName, p.prodCost, p.prodPrice
```

I used the alias `c` for the second prod to stand for 'component'. I explicitly wrote `not c.isKit` since this won't work recursively. `union all` is used rather than `union` for effeciency reasons, since they will both return the same results.

Caveats:

- This won't work recursively (e.g. if
  a kit requires components from
  another kit).
- This only works on kits
  that require only one of a particular
  item (e.g. if a time travel kit were
  to require 2 flux capacitors and 1
  Mr. Fusion, this wouldn't work).
- I didn't test this so there may be minor syntax errors.
- This only calculates the `prodStock` field; to do the other fields you would need similar logic.

If your query is much more complicated than what I assumed, I apologize, but I hope that this can help you find a solution that will work.

As for how to handle the data when you buy a kit, this assumes you would store the `prodStock` in only the component parts. So for example if you purchase a time machine from a supplier, instead of increasing the `prodStock` on the time machine product, you would increase it on the flux capacitor and the Mr. fusion.

Comment: I like the idea of the boolean. Updated my question.

Am I using the correct word for this? This is a relationship between products, or there is a better word, and this is why my question is going unnoticed?